# What happens if you manifest a creature card with morph?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-face-down-cards

If a player manifests a creature card with the morph ability, can that player pay the morph cost to turn it face up?

For example, if Anthony casts [Formless Nurturing](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Formless%20Nurturing) to manifest [Abomination of Gudul](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Abomination%20of%20Gudul), can he pay the morph cost of {2}{B}{G}{U} instead of the creature cost of {3}{B}{G}{U} to turn it face up?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes. If a creature card with Morph is manifested, the permanent it becomes may be flipped for either its creature cost or its morph cost. This is covered by the following rule [introduced in Fate Reforged](http://magic.wizards.com/en/articles/archive/feature/fate-reforged-release-notes-2015-01-14):

> **701.31c** If a card with morph is manifested, its controller may use the procedure described in rule 702.36d to turn a face-down permanent with morph face up rather than the procedure described above to turn a manifested permanent face up.

In your specific example, Anthony may choose to pay either {2}{B}{G}{U} or {3}{B}{G}{U} to flip Abomination of Gudul at any time he has priority.

For reference:

> **702.36d** Any time you have priority, you may turn a face-down permanent you control face up. This is a special action; it doesn’t use the stack (see rule 115). To do this, show all players what the permanent’s morph cost would be if it were face up, pay that cost, then turn the permanent face up.

Comment: I think it might be helpful to also quote rule 702.36d.

Comment: @murgtroid99 Done. Now that I am actually reading 702.36d, it seems to cover everything that 701.31c covers. Do you have any thoughts as to how the two rules are different? In other words, does 701.31c add anything above and beyond what 702.36d already states? Just curious.

Comment: I think 701.31c clarifies that the manifest rules do not place any restrictions on 702.36d. It's probably technically redundant because 702.36d is so general, but with both mechanics in the same set, this question is going to come up a lot, so it's probably easier to answer it explicitly in the rules.

Comment: Also, it is not expected that someone will read through and remember all the rules, so it makes sense for someone reading through the section on manifest (701.31) to be pointed towards the relevant rules on morph (702.36).

Answer (score 3):

You can pay either the morph cost or the creature's normal mana cost to flip it up.

Manifest is covered in [Mechanics of Fate Reforged](http://magic.wizards.com/en/articles/archive/feature/mechanics-fate-reforged-2014-12-29). The relevant snippet for this question:

> If you happen to manifest a card with morph, you can turn it face up either by paying its mana cost (if it's a creature card) or by paying its morph cost.

In general, when you have a question about a mechanic from a new set, a really good place to find answers about it is the mechanics article Wizards posts for the set. The title is always in the same form as this article ("Mechanics of {set name}") so they're really easy to search for.

If you want the full technical details, the comprehensive rules are the place to go ([see Rainbolt's answer](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/a/22565/409)), but if you want a practical, easy to understand answer, these articles are really useful. As a bonus, they're often published a bit before the comprehensive rules updates, so you can satisfy your curiosity sooner.